# What is the symmetry group of the totally nonnegative Grassmannian $Gr_{tnn}(k,n)$?

Tags: grassmannians, symmetric-spaces, symmetry, total-positivity

What is the symmetry group of the totally nonnegative Grassmannian $Gr_{tnn}(k,n)$? [The latter consists of those elements of the Grassmannian that can be represented by $k \times n$-matrices all of whose $k \times k$-minors have non-negative determinants and $k < n$.]

Comment: Symmetry in which category?

Comment: There is an important cyclic action on the positive Grassmannian; see this recent survey paper by Postnikov: https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.05307

Comment: For more on this cyclic action see: https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.06004